# Bouncing rectangle (Graphics g)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I'm playing around with graphics in Java. At the moment I have a rectangle that moves from left to right. I want it to start moving left once it hits the right side of the Canvas and left when it hits the right side, i have included a game loop as this will eventually turn into my first very basic game. Thanks.

P.S - I followed some tutorials for different parts of this code hence why it might be a bit messy, I'm working on it :)

Main Class:

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    private RenderHandler renderer;
    private boolean running = true;
    public static int WIDTH = 1200, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12*9;
    public static int moveX =WIDTH/2;

    public Game() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(canvas);
        setVisible(true);
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        renderer = new RenderHandler(getWidth(), getHeight());

    }


    public void update() {

    }


    public void render() {
            BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
            Graphics graphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
            super.paint(graphics);

            renderer.render(graphics);

            graphics.dispose();
            bufferStrategy.show();
    }

    public void run() {
        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        int FRAMES = 0;
        int TICKS = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double unprocessed = 0;
        double nsPerSecs = 1000000000 /60.0;
        long Timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            unprocessed += (now - lastTime) / nsPerSecs;
            lastTime  = now;

            if(unprocessed >= 1) {
                TICKS ++;
                update();
                unprocessed -= 1;
            } 
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(3); 
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FRAMES++;
            render();

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - Timer > 1000) {
                System.out.println("Ticks: " + TICKS + " FPS: " + FRAMES);
                TICKS = 0;
                FRAMES = 0;
                Timer += 1000;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        Thread gameThread = new Thread(game);
        gameThread.start();
    }

}
```

Class drawing the graphics:

```
public class RenderHandler {
public RenderHandler(int width, int height) {

}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(Game.moveX, Game.HEIGHT/2, 50, 50);
    if (Game.moveX >= Game.WIDTH) {
        Game.moveX ++;
    } else if (Game.moveX <= 0) {
        Game.moveX --;
    }else { Game.moveX++;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is you *specific* question?

Comment: @Andreas How to make the g.drawRect move left when it hits the right side of the frame / canvas

Comment: This is not the correct way to to this. First, you should never mix AWT components (Canvas) with Swing components (JFrame) Second, don't try drawing on a JFrame; you should create a JPanel in the frame and draw on the panel in its paintComponent() method . Third, you are blocking the event thread - you need to create a SwingTimer

Comment: @FredK Thank you for the help!

Comment: Don't make logical choices in render methods, these should be made as part of the update pass, which should be maintained be a state model

Comment: @MadProgrammerYes you're completely right thank you, like i said ive followed tutorials and i know its messy, ill sort this now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store current moving direction somewhere, so add this to Game class:

```
public static int deltaX = 1;
```

And replace condition in render() with

```
if (Game.moveX >= Game.WIDTH-50) {
    Game.deltaX =-1;
} else if (Game.moveX <= 0) {
    Game.deltaX =1;
}
Game.moveX += Game.deltaX;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to draw on the screen and how stuffs work, I would think that this is more about getting the logic down.

This code slice I so brutally tore from your question is right next to where the rendering takes place (a problem because I view it as rather unorganized; I would recommend game logic and rendering to take place in two different functions). It basically says that it will move right if it is beyond the right of the screen, if not, it will move left if it is beyond the left of the screen, and finally, if not, it will just move left.

```
if (Game.moveX >= Game.WIDTH) {
        Game.moveX ++;
    } else if (Game.moveX <= 0) {
        Game.moveX --;
    }else { Game.moveX++;
    }
```

If you want it to bounce, you will have to use a boolean to keep track of its moving state, or, if you want more versatility, use a pair of floats or doubles (floats are typically used in Java game design) to keep track of its position, and another for its velocity. I'm in a tight squeeze right now, I will return.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this has helped. Im not great at logic as you have probably guessed. Im new to this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to render handler instead of the current if statement in render

```
bool rol = true; // initialize this outside the method


If(Game.movex + 50 >= Game.width)
rol = false;
Else if(Game.movex <= 0)
rol = true;
If(rol)
Game.movex++;
Else
Game.movex--;
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your reply, this has worked better than mine however its still getting stuck on the right side and not bouncing back

Comment: Can you copy the new code in I just want to check something

Comment: Here is the your code corrected a little, it works perfectly now thank you!

Comment: if(Game.moveX + 50 >= Game.WIDTH){
  rol = false;
  }
  else if(Game.moveX <= 0) {
  rol = true;
  }
  if(rol) {
  Game.moveX++;
  }
  else {
  Game.moveX--;
  }

Comment: boolean rol = true; // initialize this outside the method